# Mysql Выбрать записи которых нет в таблице исходя из других таблиц

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Здраствуйте, есть такая схема бд:
[Вот часть дампа (структура и таблицы](https://pastebin.com/wW4vCKU2)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть квизы к которым прикрепляются ответы через промежуточною таблицу quiz_step_choice
А есть групы квизов к которым прикреплятся квизы описанные выше через таблицу quiz_step_group_item.

Столкнулся с трудностю написать запрос который веренет мне:

все групы квызов,в которых квизы прикрепленны к групам, не имеют прикрипленных ответов, которые прикрепленны к конкретному квизу, а так же сами варыанты ответом которые отсутствуют
К примеру:

У нас есть квиз **пол** , там 3 варианта (М,Ж, не определился)
и квиз **сколько лет** варианты(20, 30, 40)
И у нас есть 2 групы квизов в которых есть оба этих квиза

В первой групе есть все 3 варианта ответа  для каждого квиза
Во второй только 2 (М,Ж) для квиза **пол** и 3 для квиза **сколько лет**. Так вот мне нужно составить запрос который возвращал бы мне квиз **пол**, выбор (**не определился**)

Пытался выбрать такым способом:

```
SELECT choice.id, qsgi.quiz_step_group_id, qsgci.current_choice_id FROM choice
JOIN quiz_step_choice qsc on choice.id = qsc.choice_id
JOIN quiz_step ON qsc.quiz_step_id = quiz_step.id AND qsc.quiz_step_id = 20
JOIN quiz_step_group_item qsgi on quiz_step.id = qsgi.quiz_step_id
LEFT JOIN quiz_step_group_choice_item qsgci on choice.id = qsgci.current_choice_id

GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

Но запрос, вместо null, в месте где нету пересичения ставит мне выбор которого на самом деле нет в групе.
В моем конкретном случаи, если вы использывали дамп из файла прикрепленного выше, мне нужен choice.id = 94 и quiz_step_group.id = 1. Именно этот вариант присутствует в групу 2 но отсутствует в группе 1

Comment: Замените схему в картинках на набор CREATE TABLE скриптов (ненужные для вопроса таблицы, поля из таблиц, и все индексы / внешние ключи - удалите), набор INSERT INTO скриптов с тестовыми данными, эталонный ответ для этих данных.

Comment: PS. Схема потенциально противоречива. Например, запись в `quiz_step_group_choice_item` может быть связана с одной записью в `choice` напрямую, и с совсем другой через `quiz_step_choice`...

Comment: По второму замечанию соглаен - но ето временное решение, пока не будет реализован нормальный функционал по синхронизации.

Comment: К сожаления не выходит залить схему в sqlfiddle  или похожие ресурсы. Закинул схему в https://pastebin.com/wW4vCKU2. Так де прикреплю это выше

Comment: Нормально вроде погрузилось (я, правда, просил ещё и почистить - пришлось это делать самому) - [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=d1508743d968347a593e06638d04170e). Правда, 5.7 глючит, установил 5.6, какая разница... Теперь ждём "эталонный ответ для **этих** данных." С пояснениями, почему именно так.

Comment: Я же указал что я ожидают от запроса- "В моем конкретном случаи, если вы использывали дамп из файла прикрепленного выше, мне нужен choice.id = 94 и quiz_step_group.id = 1. Именно этот вариант присутствует в групу 2 но отсутствует в группе 1", если я правильно вас понял.